# Canonical Form of Nilpotent Matrices

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, random-matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given the matrix $$\hat{S}=\begin{bmatrix} 
 S & *& *&* \\
 0& S &* &* \\
0& 0& S &* \\
0&0&0&S\\ 
 \end{bmatrix} $$
where $S$  is an $n \times n$ irreducible matrix, i.e. it can not be equivalent to a  block upper-triangular matrix. The stars are arbitrary $n \times n$  matrices in $Com(S)=\{Y;  [S,Y]=SY-YS=0 \}$.
Required to prove that the above matrix is equivalent to  $$\begin{bmatrix} 
 S & I_n& 0&0 \\
 0& S &I_n &0 \\
0& 0& S &I_n \\
0&0&0&S\\ 
 \end{bmatrix} $$
Hint for the solution, is the well-known canonical form of nilpotent matrices.
The idea is that I try search fro the "well-known canonical form of nilpotent matrices", where  using the eigen vectors of a nilpotent matrix , they show that its equivalent to one whose entries are zero except the first off-diagonal  composes of ones. My difficulty is how to generalize this result to the case of blocks !!

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Are you sure you have stated the problem correctly? For instance, if all asterisks are zero, the two big matrices shown in your question are not similar to each other. When some nonzero asterisks are zero divisors (i.e. a singular matrix), -- e.g. when $S$ is a doubly stochastic matrix and the asterisks are the all-one matrices -- the two big matrices are also not necessarily similar.